# Setting up shared development machine

Tags: permissions, web-development

I have a server machine that contains 10 users. OS: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 64bit

These users are developers (mainly web developers: HTML+JS+PHP+MYSQL)

I allowed them to remote login through XRDP and VNC.

Now everything works fine but the problem in /var/www

What is the suitable permission for this directory so they don't have problems while sharing some code between them although they aren't root. All of them are simple users.

I need to know if there is a secure way of letting them share source code and at the same time each one have its own repository. I welcome any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Method (due to the bounty :))

You can do it this way if you don't want to keep all users in the same webroot. You can make different directories as webroot aliases for the /var/www/ directory. Suppose you h ave two users u1 and u2.

I supposed you already installed apace2 if not do it `sudo apt-get install apache2`

I'll make the directories /home/u1/web  and /home/u2/web to be the webroot of the users u1 and u2.

```
sudo chmod 775 home/u1/web
sudo chmod 775 home/u2/web

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Create alias (add the following to the file ) for the user u1:

```
Alias /u1 /home/u1/web
<Directory /u1>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Create alias (add the following to the file ) for the user u2:

```
Alias /u2 /home/u2/web
<Directory /u1>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now Each user can access his web root by pointing your web browser to localhost/u1 for user u1 and localhost/u2 for user u2

Answer (score 2):

You put all of these users in the same GROUP

```
usermod -g {group} {user}
```

That way all users have the same permissions. We generally use the group apache is set up with (www-data or apache).

Any changes in permissions to a file or directory on the group will change it for all.

In general files in /var/www/ can have 664 as minimum. And directories 775. Never put any of them on 777 but you can go lower.

Comment: Would this work adding them to the `www-data` group?

Comment: Yes sir/man!. Nothing wrong with doing that (editted it in)

Comment: @Rinzwind That's not what I meant. Having All users same permissions does not help!

Comment: yes it does. It will make it possible "... so they don't have problems while sharing some code between them although they aren't root". Same group = sharing code.

Comment: @Rinzwind but there are no permissions between them so they can delete each others code

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

1. create a directory inside /var/www for each user
2. change the owner of each directory to the associated user and the group to www-data group

   `sudo chown user1:www-data /var/www/user1`

   `sudo chown user2:www-data /var/www/user2`
3. Change permissions of each directory to 750 so that no user can mess up with other user's files, but keeping the ability to open the html files of others in the browser by using the permissions of the www-data group.

---

Comment: your answer sounds good +1. I need not to create folders with each user in var/www