# How to restrict changes to file permissions?

Tags: permissions

The situation:

Back to this question: [Setting up shared development machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414109/what-is-the-right-permission-for-shared-development-machine/416182#416182)

I proposed a method to create directories inside the webroot for each user in a shared environment.

I think it's perfect but there is one problem that I don't have an answer for.

I gave each user a permission of 750 for user:user and group:www-data. Now every thing is fine unless a user changes the permission of his associated directory.

The problem is how to prevent a user who own a folder from changing its permission and here I'm asking for directory permission not the files inside the directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*After looking around on different websites;*

As far as I know **only the owner** of the file(directory) **and root can use chmod** on the file.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=490296

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't help.. I really know file permissions but i also know that it could be a work over  for this problem

Comment: Explain what you mean. Are you saying that there's way for the users to bypass or what are you implying?

Comment: I mean a root can prvent some users from changing permissions for a specific directory

Comment: So you want the users to able to change permissions on _some_ but not _all_ directorier?

Comment: yes thats the point

Comment: Just make the user the owner of the file(directory)?

Comment: Please read again the question and read the answer in the link